# docker mariadb refuses to accept connections

Tags: docker

Mysql container not accepting connection from another container

```
docker network create -d bridge mysql
```

Db container

```
docker run --name mysql_db -d \
    --network mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass \
    -e MYSQL_USER=user \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=database \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% \
    mariadb 

$ docker logs mysql_db
2022-11-06 21:46:01 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

the second container is in the same network

```
$ php -r "new mysqli('mysql_db','root', 'pass','database');"

$ PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Command line code on line 1
```

from the second container

```
# ping mysql_db
PING mysql_db (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
....
--- mysql_db ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

got same results when using mysql:5.7

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in how you're starting your PHP container. If I create the `mysql` network and `mysql_db` container by copying-and-pasting your command lines, I can the start a `php` container:

```
docker run --rm -it --network mysql php:8 bash
```

Install the `mysqli` extension:

```
root@12367e04fca7:/# docker-php-ext-install mysqli
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20210902
Zend Module Api No:      20210902
Zend Extension Api No:   420210902
[...]
```

And then run your `php` command line without errors:

```
root@12367e04fca7:/# php -r "new mysqli('mysql_db','root', 'pass','database');"
root@12367e04fca7:/#
```

I can even run this example from the documentation:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('mysql_db','root', 'pass','database');
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    printf("connection failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error());
    exit();
}

$res = $con->query("SELECT VERSION()");
if ($res) {

    $row = $res->fetch_row();
    echo $row[0];
}

$res->close();
$con->close();
?>
```

Which will output (on my system):

```
10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I am using docker inside openwrt so the problem mite be there